# Parse XML com Shell Script

Tags: xml

Eu tenho a seguinte estrutura dentro de um arquivo XML:

```
<TestCase name="A" priority="">
  <Test name="A1" result="pass" />
  <Test name="A2" result="pass"/>
</TestCase>
<TestCase name="B" priority="">
  <Test name="B1" result="pass" />
  <Test name="B2" result="pass"/>
</TestCase>
```

Utilizando shell script, como faço para ler e percorrer as tags  e suas subtags, afim de imprimir o resultado:

```
A
 A1 - pass
 A2 - pass
B
 B1 - pass
 B2 - pass
```

Comment: Qual shell? bash? CMD? PS?

Comment: O shell é bash.

Answer (score 1):

O teu exemplo não é XML bem formado...

Para processar XML convém usar uma ferramenta que inclua um Parser de XML.
Para comando de linha sugeria algo com `xmllint` ou `xmlstarlet` (há outros excelentes)

Usando expressões regulares também se pode fazer qualquer coisa se o ficheiro for
muito simples e regular. 
Seguidamente vai um exemplo Perl (pode-se fazer algo semelhante
em sed, awk, python) mas que está agarrado ao exemplo apresentado...

```
perl -nE '/name="(.*?)".*result="(.*?)"/ and say " $1 - $2"  or
          /name="(.*?)"/                 and say $1'    file.xml
```